# Web.Config.Release Transform not updating Keys,etc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

It appears that my release config is not transforming properly.

This is the setup:

### Web.Config

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="key1" value="1"/>
   <add key="key2" value="1"/>
   <add key="key3" value="1"/>
   <add key="key4" value="1"/>
   <add key="key5" value="1"/>
   <add key="key6" value="1"/>
<appSettings>
```

### Web.Config.Release

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="key1" value="0" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
   <add key="key2" value="0" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
   <add key="key3" value="0" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
<appSettings>
```

And this is what gets published

### Web.Config (Published)

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="key3" value="0"/>
   <add key="key1" value="1"/>
   <add key="key2" value="1"/>
   <add key="key3" value="1"/>
   <add key="key4" value="1"/>
   <add key="key5" value="1"/>
   <add key="key6" value="1"/>
<appSettings>
```

Weird, anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For appSettings, since all tag is `<add>`, the way to transform is different:

```
 <add key="key1" value="0" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
```